# RInno detailed example with Shiny in RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, inno-setup

I need to make multiple Shiny apps, exceeding my 5 app allowance in the free version of `shiny.io`. So I am trying to use `RInno`. I know this is ridiculous, but the [beginner's tutorial for RInno](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) seems too sparse for me (they do call it a 'minimal example'). I simply cannot figure out what I am meant to do. In the tutorial, a pre-loaded 'example' app is used to demonstrate.

```
# If you don't have development tools, install them
install.packages("devtools"); require(devtools)

# Use install_github to get RInno
devtools::install_github("ficonsulting/RInno",  build_vignettes = TRUE)

# Require Package
require(RInno)

# Use RInno to get Inno Setup
RInno::install_inno()

# Example app included with RInno package
example_app(wd = getwd())

# Build an installer
create_app(app_name = "Your appname", app_dir = "app")
compile_iss()
```

When I run this in RStudio, a folder called `app` appears in my working directory. I open it to find the following (screen shot):

[image]

What do I do now? I have tried opening 'Your appname' and following the set up instructions (clicking next>next>next>>>finish). This puts a short cut called 'Your appname' on my desktop. I open this but get the error:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Opening the `html` folder in the `app` folder from the first screen shot reveals a html of a plot that I presume is the example. This would suit me just fine for my own needs. However when I have tried to launch an existing app of my own with something like

```
create_app(app_name = "existing app", app_dir = "path/to/existing/app")
compile_iss()
```

Then I don't even get a `html` folder like the one in the screen shot here!
The script for my existing `shiny` app is in `RStudio`, is this right? Or does it need to be in Inno Setup Script?

Any pointers would be really great. Cheers

Comment: Can you share your app's `log/error.log`? I've never seen this issue, and there might be some clues in that log.

Comment: As for the html folder, if there is a sub-directory called `html` in your `app_dir`, RInno should pick that up and deliver it with your .exe